# White light interferometer

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, interference

I am building white-light Michaelson interferometer and I am registering interference in frequency domain via spectrometer. I read an article, where the same is done (just Mach-Zender interferometer) and it is said, that Fourier trasform gives direct access to absolute path-length difference:

[image]

But if we apply Fourier transform to spectra (x axis is frequency in Hz), Fourier transform will gives us something in seconds (1/Hz), not in meters. My question is, how it is done here? Is "seconds" axis multiplied by c (light speed), or something different is applied? What relation is used here?

Article reference: Attosecond beamline with actively stabilized and spatially separated beam paths
M. Huppert, I. Jordan, and H. J. Wörner
http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.4937623

Comment: could you provide a reference for the article?

Comment: Yes, I should have added reference to main question too.

Attosecond beamline with actively stabilized and spatially separated beam paths
M. Huppert, I. Jordan, and H. J. Wörner
http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.4937623

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the fact that light travels at speed $c$ is implicit in the conversions between units here. What you’re actually measuring is an interferogram with $x$ (the mirror position) as the independent axis. Then to convert to frequency, you’ll need to include $c$ in your calculation. And don’t forget that in a Michelson interferometer, a change of mirror position $x$ corresponds to a change in light path length of $2x$!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Just day after my question I uploaded my modulated spectra to MatLAB and wrote simple FFT code. Changed wavelength axis to frequency by dividing *c* by wavelength, did FFT and I got FFT of spectra vs time. I multiplied time axis again by *c* and got distance in meters. And the center of modulation frequency peak gave me direct absolute path difference, which was, like you said, double mirror position.

Comment: @VytautasSirautas nice work!